# UIViewController interfaceOrientation Property Deprecated

Tags: ios, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

I am currently utilizing the *interfaceProperty* of my UIViewController that as of iOS 8 has been deprecated.

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0,8_0);
```

I am using said property for determining where the physical Home button is orientated for accelerometer and gravity vector corrections. UIDeviceOrientation is not a suitable replacement because these corrections are actually applied to the *user interface*.

I have searched for suitable refactoring advice, however, they do not apply to my use of the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using

[UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarOrientation)

It will return a [UIInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientation) value which you can use to get the interface orientation of the device.

Comment: That returns UIDeviceOrientation which is not the same as UIInterfaceOrientation per Apple's documentation.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock The documentation link in my answer mentions the return type as UIInterfaceOrientation. So can you please provide a source where the return type is UIDeviceOrientation?

Comment: My apologies - I have looked at too many orientation properties for my own good today and got confused.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Glad i was of help. Can you remove your downvote?

Comment: I tried; it says you have to edit your answer. Maybe add a little more information like its definition?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Can you try now?